# Text over image not showing in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, text

so I placed some links (text) over an image and in desktop browsers everything is working just fine, however, once you open it in a mobile browser, the text is not showing up. Here's my css:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#dm {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 18.8%;
    width: 13.5%;
    height: 64.8%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}


h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 59%;
    left: 21.7%;
    width: 78%;
}


h2>a {
    color: #f6f6f6;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-shadow: #000000 10% 10% 20%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

And HTML code:

```
<div id="header">
<img src="header.png" border="0" id="dm">
<a id="logo" href="index.html"></a>
<h2><a href="slider">Domů</a> <a href="slider">O nás</a> <a href="slider">Web & Grafický design</a> <a href="slider">Digitální kresba</a> <a href="slider">Pro firmy</a> <a href="slider">Ostatní služby</a> <a href="slider">Portfolio</a> <a href="slider">Faq</a> <a href="slider">Kontakt</a></h2>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The font size you have set for the links is `font-size: 1.3vw;`, which means they will appear at 1.3% of the viewport width.

For desktop browsers with screen width of at least 1000px, it will show up as at least 13px which is totally fine.

For a mobile browser, if your device screen is 640px wide, it will only appear as ~8px which is way too small, which is probably why you couldn't see it. Besides, most mobile devices have width of between 320px and 400+px if viewed at portrait mode, so that makes the text even smaller.

When I put it at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vqpuhdj/), I thought there was no text until I placed a grey placeholder image. You should have used `em` instead of `vw` for the font size if you want to scale it.